# Is there a benefit to use println() to print only Strings?

Tags: swift, println

Why use `println("hello")` to print the string `hello` when the output would show up on the righthand side if I simply wrote `"hello"`? Is there really any benefit and `println()` is used mainly for outputting variables values?

Comment: Are you asking about when you're in a Playground? Because yes, there, there's no real benefit, but in an actual project, you can't just leave a String in the middle of your code and expect it to do something. See [Introduction to the Swift REPL](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=18).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on which situation you are using println() in.

### Playground

### Default

In the default playground, both `println(someString)` and just `someString` on a line by itself will both display the exact same output on the right-hand gutter.  In that case they are identical.

### Assistant Editor

In a playground you can also open the Assistant editor. You can do this in the menu via View → Assistant Editor → Show Assistant Editor (or the keyboard shortcut ⌥⌘⏎ (main enter key right next to the letters)).

To show a printed string there, you must use `println()`.  The gutter is more of a quicklook bar, to give you a sense of what is there.  The assistant editor has a console, and to print to it you use `println()`.

The assistant editor has other uses, like showing previews of views that are being tested, but for this question, that is the major difference between a `String` on a single line, and a `println()` statement.

### Project

In a real project, there are times when you want to test something, like [AstroCB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28533933/is-there-a-benefit-to-use-println-to-print-only-strings#comment45382501_28533933) was mentioning, you might want to print some text to console.  So if you wanted something to print to the console as certain functions or parts of loops were completed, you would use `println()` to print something to the console.  After running the app, you can see if what you expected to happen did actually do so by only looking at the console.

For debugging, you can use plain `Strings` in `println()` to see if the program did what you expected, or to find where something was skipped.

Many other situations do make it nicer to just `println()` out a formatted string of variable values.  For instance, if you expect a certain value for a variable, but it seems to be incorrect when run, you can pepper the method that you are working on that variable with

```
println("X = \(myXValue)")
```

to see how it is being affected without having to single-step through the code every time.